# Looking for recently modified jobs in SAS meta data: How do I make metadata_getnobj("Job?@MetadataUpdated > '01May2020:00:00:00'dt") work?

Tags: sas, metadata

With this type of code, I can find out details about a single job we created in DI studio

```
data report_info;
    length uri $256 Date $40;
    n_rep=metadata_getnobj("Job?@Name = 'MY_JOB_NAME'", 1, uri);
    rc=metadata_getattr(uri, "MetadataUpdated", Date);

    * more calls to metadata_getattr and metadata_getnasn *;
run;
```

Other possible arguments for `metadata_getnobj` are

- `"Job?@Name contians '_EDW_'"`, which would give me all jobs for our Enterprise Data Warehouse (EDW)
- `"Job?@Name contains 'AML' and @Desc contains 'cash flow')"`, which will return jobs about Cash Flow in our Anti Money Laundering (AML) reports

To find out which jobs were recently modified, I tried different options, including

- `"Job?@MetadataUpdated > '01May2020:00:00:00'dt"`
- `"Job?@MetadataModifed gt '01May2020:00:00:00'dt"`
- `"Job?@MetadataModifed contains 'May2020'"`

but they don't give results. Can anybody correct these?

Is there a manual for the syntax of these requests?

Comment: great question.  Metadata query syntax is a dark art :-)

Comment: As I don't find a manual on URI, we can only learn from example. Interesting are https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrmeta&docsetTarget=n16hsug0xiczidn141ezc7rlz8rb.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en and statements like this one generated by EG: `Libname EDW_DS META  LIBURI="SASLibrary?*[@Name='L_EDW_DS'][DeployedComponents/ServerContext[@Name='SASApp']]";`

Comment: And this https://communities.sas.com/t5/Administration-and-Deployment/Listing-Metadata-libraries/td-p/359558

Comment: That is an interesting libname indeed!  I guess they have two libraries with the same name, hence the approach?  As for the article, interesting point on session encoding.  A faster approach for extracting libraries though is here:  https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/meta/mm_getlibs.sas

Comment: back to your original question - did you try sending as raw (numeric) datetime values, instead of datetime literals?